# How to recover an LVM mirror after a phsyical device failure?

Tags: lvm, mirroring

I had a drive fail in LVM, it shows up as unknown now. The volume group 'vmimages' was setup as a mirror

```
  WARNING: Device for PV BejWGq-OBoi-RQ03-2pJU-ow0e-KORt-MbkW8F not found or rejected by a filter.
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               [unknown]
  VG Name               vmimages
  PV Size               <2.73 TiB / not usable 4.46 MiB
  Allocatable           yes 
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              715396
  Free PE               692353
  Allocated PE          23043
  PV UUID               BejWGq-OBoi-RQ03-2pJU-ow0e-KORt-MbkW8F

  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sde1
  VG Name               vmimages
  PV Size               651.92 GiB / not usable 3.00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes 
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              166892
  Free PE               143852
  Allocated PE          23040
  PV UUID               CC5Aif-KJRz-ZrmB-FfLD-ge6o-cJvR-s8zPwX

  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sdc1
  VG Name               vmimages
  PV Size               <652.86 GiB / not usable 0   
  Allocatable           yes 
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              167131
  Free PE               167131
  Allocated PE          0
  PV UUID               Vmo1s7-8LYw-uuNq-B4QE-CSSi-QEK8-Sf1oo4

  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sdb
  VG Name               main
  PV Size               <5.46 TiB / not usable <2.59 MiB
  Allocatable           yes 
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              1430791
  Free PE               7153
  Allocated PE          1423638
  PV UUID               1CyYd3-AzTO-2nez-BsdC-7k5I-W2GV-5j9b6A

  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sdd
  VG Name               main
  PV Size               <7.28 TiB / not usable <1.34 MiB
  Allocatable           yes 
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              1907721
  Free PE               484084
  Allocated PE          1423637
  PV UUID               eCe1ep-zSLG-w6XE-p9QI-eUY5-46ZH-EQNmEW

None of the logical volumes in the VG are available

$ sudo lvdisplay vmimages
  WARNING: Device for PV BejWGq-OBoi-RQ03-2pJU-ow0e-KORt-MbkW8F not found or rejected by a filter.
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/vmimages/unifi
  LV Name                unifi
  VG Name                vmimages
  LV UUID                4sxn41-4ZO2-Ivkw-Jeq3-xITu-jRSl-Zqod0k
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time maus, 2018-06-22 03:06:17 +0000
  LV Status              NOT available
  LV Size                30.00 GiB
  Current LE             7680
  Mirrored volumes       2
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/vmimages/gateway
  LV Name                gateway
  VG Name                vmimages
  LV UUID                9MXECi-m5bP-0RuN-4Ihs-rDhO-RMTJ-uPrac8
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time maus, 2018-06-23 17:39:32 +0000
  LV Status              NOT available
  LV Size                30.00 GiB
  Current LE             7680
  Mirrored volumes       2
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/vmimages/homeassistant
  LV Name                homeassistant
  VG Name                vmimages
  LV UUID                44xHsi-EW4q-xrLz-fzYF-RCGd-3FSE-802Mab
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time maus, 2018-07-08 19:53:47 +0000
  LV Status              NOT available
  LV Size                30.00 GiB
  Current LE             7680
  Mirrored volumes       2
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
```

I have tried starting one of my LVs in degraded mode, but this does nothing. The man page suggests this doesn't work for mirrors, but offers no alternative or explanation why.

```
$ sudo lvchange -ay --activationmode degraded /dev/vmimages/unifi
  WARNING: Device for PV BejWGq-OBoi-RQ03-2pJU-ow0e-KORt-MbkW8F not found or rejected by a filter.
  Refusing activation of partial LV vmimages/unifi.  Use '--activationmode partial' to override.
```

My understanding is I should not ever be using 'partial' to activate an Lv

I double checked, I appear to have a complete copy on one of the existing PVs

```
$ sudo pvs /dev/sde1 --segments -o +lv_name +lv_size
  Failed to find device for physical volume "+lv_size".
  WARNING: Device for PV BejWGq-OBoi-RQ03-2pJU-ow0e-KORt-MbkW8F not found or rejected by a filter.
  PV         VG       Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree   Start SSize  LV                      
  /dev/sde1  vmimages lvm2 a--  651.92g 561.92g     0   7680 [unifi_mimage_0]        
  /dev/sde1  vmimages lvm2 a--  651.92g 561.92g  7680   7680 [gateway_mimage_0]      
  /dev/sde1  vmimages lvm2 a--  651.92g 561.92g 15360   7680 [homeassistant_mimage_0]
  /dev/sde1  vmimages lvm2 a--  651.92g 561.92g 23040 143852
```

I have variously also tried converting the mirror to a non-mirror. This can't be done without activation first. I've also tried removing missing devices. LVM then tells me that the LVs need to be repaired (I do not know what this means) or removed (obviously not what I want).

I have no idea how to proceed here. How do I get LVM to activate my Logical Volume and then use my new PV /dev/sdc1 to basically re-mirror the data? I'm assuming my data is actuall yhere on /dev/sde1 but just in limbo

Comment: I have the exact same problem. @Eric Urban did you find a solution youself? Sorry for asking, but as its 2 months since you posted you question, I guess there is a possibility that you found a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same issue here, solved in somewhat hackish way using `dd`.

We [have](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/187236/grub2-lvm2-raid1-boot)
setup root on LVM three years ago.  Now one of the physical disks
failed, completely:

```
pier41:~# hdparm -I /dev/sdb
/dev/sdb:
 HDIO_DRIVE_CMD(identify) failed: Input/output error
```

There is an [LVM mirror recovery instruction](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/logical_volume_manager_administration/mirrorrecover) which reads:

> Any write activity to the mirrored volume causes LVM to detect the failed mirror. When this occurs, LVM converts the mirror into a single linear volume.

Unfortunately this statement appears to be incorrect, at least for our
Debian 10 Buster, kernel version 4.19.  The auto-conversion didn't
happen, `/dev/vg0/root` remained mirrored.  Reading some files from
the volume worked thanks to the kernel page cache, reading some other
files would give I/O error.  I was able to save `/etc/lvm/lvm.conf`
and `/etc/lvm/backup/vg0`.  Finally the system went unusable and had to
be rebooted the hard way, `echo b > /proc/sysrq-trigger`.

I have prepared replacement disk on another machine:

```
# fdisk /dev/sdX
# pvcreate --uuid [for sdb2 in ./lvm.conf] --restorefile backup/vg0 /dev/sdX2
```

replaced the failed disk by the replacement disk and tried to boot --
no success, unable to mount root.  OK, booted from rescue flash.

```
pier41:~# lvdisplay -m /dev/vg0/root
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/vg0/root
  LV Name                root
  VG Name                vg0
  LV UUID                xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time pier41, 2019-01-21 15:25:14 +0300
  LV Status              NOT available
  LV Size                <20.29 GiB
  Current LE             5194
  Mirrored volumes       2
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto

  --- Segments ---
  Logical extents 0 to 5193:
    Type                raid1
    Monitoring
    Raid Data LV 0
      Logical volume    root_rimage_0
      Logical extents   0 to 5193
    Raid Data LV 1
      Logical volume    root_rimage_1
      Logical extents   0 to 5193
    Raid Metadata LV 0  root_rmeta_0
    Raid Metadata LV 1  root_rmeta_1
```

Other (non-mirrored) LVs all have `LV Status available`. Converting
`/dev/vg0/root` from mirrored to plain LV doesn't work indeed:

```
# lvconvert -m0 /dev/vg0/root
  vg0/root must be active to perform this operation
# lvchange -ay --activationmode degraded /dev/vg0/root
  device-mapper: reload ioctl on (253:122) failed: Invalid argument
```

But we can use the mapping reported by `lvdisplay -m` to copy the data from the healthy underlying PV (/dev/sda2) manually.  Create a new LV `/dev/vg0/root3` to copy the data to:

```
# lvcreate -n root3 -l 5194 vg0 /dev/sdb3
```

We explicitly specify the target PV (`/dev/sdb3`) lest LVM attempted to create the LV on a failed PV.

The structure of a PV is simple: it begins with a metadata area, followed by a large array of PEs numbered from 0 on.  We can find the PE size using `pvdisplay` and the offset to PE_0 using `pvck`:

```
pier41:~# pvdisplay /dev/sda2 | grep 'PE Size'
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
pier41:~# pvck /dev/sda2
  Found label on /dev/sda2, sector 1, type=LVM2 001
  Found text metadata area: offset=4096, size=1044480
pier41:~> expr 4096 + 1044480
1048576
```

The offset of 1048576 bytes is exactly 2^20 = 1MiB, so we can
conveniently operate by 1MiB `dd` blocks:

```
# dd < /dev/sdb2 > /dev/vg0/root3 bs=1M skip=1 count=20776
```

where 20776=5194*4 is the `root` LV size in 1MiB blocks.  Given the
only segment to copy, we could as well omit `count=` and simply copy
till `/dev/vg0/root3` is full.

After `dd` finishes, make sure the data we have copied are a
filesystem indeed:

```
# fsck /dev/vg0/root3
```

At this point I have used `/etc/lvm` from the recovered `root3` LV to
complete metadata reconstruction on the replacement disk:

```
# mount /dev/vg0/root3 /mnt
# vgcfgrestore --file /mnt/etc/lvm/backup/vg0 vg0
# umount /mnt
```

Finally, I renamed LVs to boot from the restored LV:

```
# lvrename vg0 root rootfail
# lvrename vg0 root3 root
# reboot
```

Now the system booted fine.  The next step was restoring data in all non-mirrored LVs, which is omitted as unrelated to the question.

## UPDATE

While working on recreating the mirroring setup, I found a simpler solution: boldly remove the "NOT available" mirrored LV, and then recreate a linear LV in the same place on the healthy PV:

```
pier41:~# lvremove /dev/vg0/rootfail
  Logical volume "rootfail" successfully removed
pier41:~# lvcreate -Zn -Wn -n root4 -l 5194 vg0 /dev/sda2:0-5193
  WARNING: Logical volume vg0/root4 not zeroed.
  Logical volume "root4" created.
pier41:~# fsck /dev/vg0/root4
(journal replay, minor corrections, OK)
```

The options `-Zn` and `-Wn` disable zeroing the first 4KB of the LV and filesystem signature detection and wiping which `lvcreate` normally does (see `man lvcreate`).  If you forget them, `fsck` will moan a lot but cope anyway, no files lost.

This solution does not require additional space (`root3`) for copying the filesystem.